# PHP SOAP Client disable response validation

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I am having an issue with a php soap client call. The soap fault happens with an XSD field like this:

```
<xsd:element name="CUST_PO_NUMBER" type="xsd:long"/>
```

The soap fault is this:

> SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: Violation of encoding rules

And the problem happens when this field CUST_PO_NUMBER has a string. Using SoapUI to test, I checked the response validation checkbox and the error it throws is:

> line 19: Invalid decimal value: unexpected char '32'

So the only thing I can think to solve this is to disable php soap client response validation. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with the input definition of the webservice, the oracle admin had to change the definition so it could accept string instead of long.